# Android: How to schedule?

Tags: android

In my app I would like that a certain method of mine (call it toSched) will run at a given time in the future (I'm using `Timestamp` for knowing when).

How can this be done, and is it possible to do it even if the phone is turned off (assume there is enough battery) ?

*I know I should use `AlarmManager` but I'm not sure how

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a timer in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [Android Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). You do it by creating a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) (which is what you want to run) and then calling the [set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method. Checkout this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager) post for more info.

What most people do is create a PendingIntent that is a broadcast. Then they create a broadcast receiver to receive that broadcast and do what ever is supposed to be done. [Here's](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) an example of "calling a method" to start an activity. But you can just put your own arbitrary code in the receiver to do what ever random task.

Comment: I read some posts and tried to understand exactly what to do, but I don't understand...
Can you please add a code example ? (I looked at some code examples but none tried to scheduale a method)

Comment: I edited my answer and added a little bit about how most people use the alarm manager to do a particular task sometime in the future.

Comment: I tried using the code in the example but I'm getting an error on "Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);" what is ctx ?
edit : there is also a problem with the first parameter of the next line

Comment: I'm guess ctx just means context. You have to give the Intent a context in which to run.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the meaning of the context in which it runs...what should I give as the first parameter ?

Comment: Please look at the Intent API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways of looking at this.  One alternative (the one I think you're looking for) is discussed in this Stack Overflow thread:

- [How to set a timer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android)

Another is to make sure your program gets *invoked* when you need it to:

- [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

  ... or ...
- [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252907/how-to-set-a-persistent-regular-schedule-in-android)